# SOAP Web Service issue

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am developing an android application which will call soap web service. SOAP web service is developed in .Net. I found that in android, We can call SOAP (wsdl based) web service. I did same for my app but I got different response than web. I am elaborating the issue...

My Question is:
I have used below code for code web service call:

```
    SOAP_ACTION  = Constants.ACTION + "o1001";
    METHOD_NAME  = "o1001";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    request.addProperty (


    "p1",email);
    request.addProperty (

    "p2",pass);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject (request);
    envelope.dotNet  = true;

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constants.URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug  = true;
    String s = "";


        try {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        s = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
        Log.v("Soap Webservice", s);
    }
    catch (Exception e


        ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return s ;
```

For same web service, When I call from Online SOAP Client it gives me perfect response but when I used above code in Android, It gives me wrong response.

Please suggest me, whether anything is wrong in my code or do I need to add something for getting exact response.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an Android person (yet), but could you tell us how you incorporated the information from the WSDL into the above Java code?  Also, where is the endpoint URL listed?

Answer (score 0):

I am using ksoap2 and code look like this :

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.setOutputSoapObject (request);
envelope.dotNet  = true;
HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(url);

request.addProperty ("userName", etUserName.getText().toString());
ht.call (SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
```

Here, you get the response using `envelope.getResponse()` or `envelope.bodyIn()`. You either get Object or Primitive type based on your response.

Comment: I have tried above code but it gives me following Error like, NullpointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object refrence. Now What to do?

Comment: I have mentioned in above comment.

Comment: You are trying to get length of null so you get this error. Fix your code. Debug your code and see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this it will work,Call This Method inside your **Async task Doinbackground,**

```
public void getdata(String SearchValue) 
        {
            // Create request
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE2, METHOD_NAME2);



            PropertyInfo pi4 = new PropertyInfo();
            pi4.setName("City");
            pi4.setValue(SearchValue);// get the string that is to be sent to the webservice
            pi4.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(pi4);

            // Create envelope
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            // Set output SOAP object
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            // Create HTTP call object
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL2);

            try {
                // Invole web service
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION2, envelope);
                // Get the response
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

                //Converting string to Array list
                  ArrayList<String> Servciecityname_arr= new ArrayList<String>();


                if ((response.toString()).contains("{")) 
                {

                    SoapObject rep = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                    JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(rep.getPropertyAsString(0));
                    for (int i = 0; i < jr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.get(i);


                           Cityname = jb.getString("CityName123");


                           Servciecityname_arr.add(Cityname);

                    }

                    CITYNAME = new String[Servciecityname_arr.size()];
                    CITYNAME = Servciecityname_arr.toArray(CITYNAME);


                } 
                else
                {
                    Status_Response = response.toString();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG2, "Error in catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: I did the same but unfortunately I got the same result :(